# Seeking recommendations on how to decouple JS code from views

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, decoupling

JavaScript plays an increasingly important role in most web solutions, but I find that it is much harder to decouple the JS code from the view specifics than it is for the server-side code.

What techniques are people using to decouple the JS code, in order to reduce the maintenance burden and to make it as resilient to minor view changes as possible?

To provide a concrete example, I have a view that looks sort of like the following:

```
<div id="signin" class="auth">
    <h2>Sign in</h2>
    <div id="resultbox" class="box" style="display: none;"></div>

    <div class="form">
        <p>Required fields are marked <span class="yellow">*</span></p>
        <form action="@Url.Action( MVC.Account.Authenticate() )" method="post" id="authform">
            <label for="Identification">Alias or email <span class="yellow">*</span></label></p>
            @Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.Identification, new { size="22", tabindex="1" } )

            <label for="Password">Password <span class="yellow">*</span></label></p>
            @Html.PasswordFor( m => m.Password, new { size="22", tabindex="2" } )

            <a href="#" class="but_styled" id="btn_signin" tabindex="3">Sign in</a>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The JS part is split into two files - the first is my "business logic" class and the second is used mostly for wiring:

```
(function (pp, $, undefined) {
    pp.account = {};

    function hideResultBox() {
        var box = $('#resultbox');
        box.hide();
        box.removeClass('info_box').removeClass('error_box');
    }
    function showResultBox(result) {
        var box = $('#resultbox');
        if (result.Success === true) {
            $('#resultbox_content').html(result.Message);
            box.addClass('info_box').show();
        } else {
            $('#resultbox_content').html(result.Message);
            box.addClass('error_box').show();
            var messages = '';
            for (var error in result.Errors) {
                messages += '<li>' + result.Errors[error] + '</li>';
            }
            if (messages !== '')
                $('#resultbox_content').append('<br /><ul>' + messages + '</ul>');
        }
    }

    pp.account.authenticate = function (data) {
        hideResultBox();
        $.post('/account/authenticate', data, function (result) {
            showResultBox(result);
            if (result.Success === true) {
                setTimeout(function () { window.location = result.Url; }, 1000);
            }
        });
    };
})(window.pressplay = window.pressplay || {}, jQuery);
```

And the wiring part:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#signin a').live('click', function () {
        var form = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
        pressplay.account.authenticate(form);
        return false;
    });
});
```

The problem with the code above is how closely it is tied to how the view looks (element ids that must be present, structure, etc.), but I have no good ideas on how it could be improved.

It just seems to me that, if I continue down this path, the JS files end up being a mess of properly encapsulated logic combined with all sorts of view-specific stuff.

Is this the best I can hope to do or are there any techniques I can apply to avoid some of this mess?

My own ideas on how to improve this revolve around building some sort of server-side generated "element selectors" JS class, such that I could write the JS without using quite as many string references to classes and element ids. But I am not sure how one would go about generating that or whether it'll just be worse to maintain in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some thoughts:

- Don't base functionality on element "id" values, except for view features that really do involve elements that are "naturally" unique.  Use classes instead whenever possible.
- Use "data-" attributes to communicate feature configuration information from HTML to JavaScript. (But don't put code in your "data-" attributes; in my opinion that's a really terrible idea. Sorry about that, fans of [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com). To each his own.)
- Use an event pub/sub system to communicate between feature "bundles" to keep interdependencies under control.
- Use `<body>` classes to characterize different sorts of pages in order to increase the efficiency of your "wiring".  That way, feature code can tell very quickly whether it needs to be even considered for a given page.

*edit* — to clarify the last one: let's say you've got some features that have to do with `<form>` pages, like date pickers, or auto-complete inputs, or other things like that.  Sometimes there are features that only make sense for certain *kinds* of forms.  In such cases, using a body class can make it simple to figure out whether a feature should bother to look around the DOM for elements to affect:

```
if ($('body').is('.password-form')) { 
  // perform specific initializations
}
```

The web application I'm currently involved with isn't too big, but it's not trivial either. I find that I can keep just one big collection of JavaScript for the entire site and include it identically on every page, and I don't have any performance concerns (currently) (well IE7 is slow, but this technique is not the cause of that).

Comment: Could you perhaps provide examples for the last two bullets (or link to something that does)? I'm not entirely sure how to translate the suggestions into something tangible that I could apply.

Comment: The third bullet is about a design pattern called `Publisher/Subscriber`: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish/subscribe

Comment: +1, also because you mention usage of data-attributes! Well remembered. =)

Comment: The fourth bullet, I think suggests you do this in your body element: `<body class="GalleryPage">` for the gallery page, and `<body class="MainPage">` for the main page... am I right?

Comment: @MiguelAngelo I do understand the pub/sub pattern, but am not sure how it would translate to JS. Do I need a broker of some sort? Are there good libraries to facilitate this or is this a hand-rolled thing?

Comment: I wouldn't use a library for that, it seems to be an overkill. I don't think that pub/sub is a good pattern in this case, it is intended for network messaging systems, such as apps that comunicate via webservies, not to comunicate between javascripts, I think this would be an over-square-kill. =)

Comment: The reason pub/sub is useful for JavaScript, I think, is that (A) it's really easy to implement, and (B) JavaScript supported features tend to "overlap" in their control of page elements, particularly with `<form>` elements. I find that it's common for completely unrelated features to require back-and-forth notifications, and pub/sub is a cleaner way to do this than (for example) directly triggering events on elements. You can of course use something like jQuery "invented" events to build a pub/sub system, by (for example) triggering handlers on `<body>` or something.

Answer (score 1):

The javascript is still a part of your view, so I don't believe is too bad of a design to have your javascript being intertwined with your view.

As far as what could be done to make life easier, I think you really need to do whatever you can to find common javascript coding situations, and refactor them out of the view, and into a common library where it can be used and reused.  For example, if you rewrote your hideResultBox to look like this:

```
function hideElement(var jqElementSelector, var cssClass1, var cssClass2 var cssClass3) {
    var element = $(jqElementSelector);
    element.hide();
    element.removeClass(cssClass1).removeClass(cssClass2).removeClass(cssClass3);
}
```

And then you could replace your call in this view to be this:

```
CommonLib.hideElement('#resultbox', 'info_box', 'error_box');
```

This way at least you don't have as much javascript to maintain.  It would also make it easier to generate the javascript call points from the server, since you're not passing in logic, just names & or ids, and not have to worry about loosing any sort of javascript intellisense abilities in your javascript logic.

Comment: That makes sense, but seems to only solve a minor part of the problem. I'd still have a reasonably tight coupling, though as you say maybe it's part of the view and I should just learn to live with it ;)

Comment: If used religiously, the javascript for your view would have little to no logic to it, which is about the best one can hope for I imagine.

Comment: True, but I'd still need to call the methods and pass in the appropriate values.. and the calls might be located inside other code elsewhere. Eventually my "public api" methods will have 100 parameters to encompass all the selectors needed inside a given call graph, which I don't imagine as being an ideal solution.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of IDs, I'd think in a more *"functional way"*...
that is, first think about what is the function of the javascript code,
then make the code in a way that it can be used by your view.

Do you see the difference?

The way you are doing is: view first, then javascript code... what I suggest is: **javascript first and then the view elements**. This way you are quite sure you are coding a reusable javascript code-base.

Instead of using IDs, use classes. Make the code like it was a general purpose lib, that you can reuse. Do not require fixed structure, for example ".myClass div a"... that div is killing reusability... replace it by some inner class: ".myClass .innerClass a", this way you can apply the classes to your view, and not let the view dominate the code.

**Minimize as much as you can the javascript code put directly in your views.** Just use method calls to your own libraries, use simple and descriptive method names. Try to put your javascript together. Try not using declarative javascript... as I see you already do this. This is the way to go! =)

Don't worry about maintainability, because decoupling is a proved way of increasing maintainability.

Comment: Good suggestions, especially the tip for getting around the fixed structure. I'll have to try JS-first, but somehow it feels like writing logic before I know that I'll need it. I'll give it a try :)

Comment: *Then do not write logic before knowing what you need!* But also, *do not let you discover what you need only when you get your hands on your view*. Your first view, should be just a mock-up, then you make the code, and finally you go back to your mock-up view, and adapt it to the code. =)

Comment: I like that! It'l be hard for me to use in my current project though, as I purchased a web template with a ton of different pages and styles. I'm modifying them as I go, but am more or less starting out with a static view that is close to finished. Next time I'll hire somebody to style the thing after the fact instead =)

Comment: Don't be pessimistic, better done than not done at all. The "as I go" phrase is powerful one. In your case I suggest you to use, say 20% of the time in refactoring and 80% in your core business development... I say that because maintainability issue is like a desease, when you get to know you are low on it, its too late.